# How to create a new tag

Tags: support, tags

How to create a new tag which I didn't find in the tag list. It might be an important tag.
I also want to create it to earn a badge

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146949/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One needs [300 reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) to create tags. At that stage, just using a new tag on a question creates it.

Try not to make narrow/redundant/meta tags, though. It's best not to look at it from a badges point of view.

Comment: NB: [Limit has changed from 300 to 1k](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5616/2451).